# Build not working but dev mode does - Invalid Page Export Field

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my next.js portfolio to vercel and getting the following error when trying to build:

> Type error: Page "app/portfolio/list/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
> "PortfolioPage" is not a valid Page export field.
> Error: Command "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build" exited with 1

Here is the code in the file referenced in the error

```
import { SideBar } from "@/app/components";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";
import Link from "next/link";
import ProjectFilter from "./ProjectFilter";
import { Primary } from "@prisma/client";
import { Metadata } from "next";

const styles =
  "fixed right-0 top-4 h-full flex flex-col pr-8 gap-10 justify-center";

interface Props {
  searchParams: { language:  Primary };
}

export const PortfolioPage = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {

  const primary_languages = Object.values(Primary);
  const language = primary_languages.includes(searchParams.language)
    ? searchParams.language
    : undefined;

  const projects = await prisma.project.findMany({
    where: {
      primary_language: language
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="mx-2 pt-8 px-14 bg-stone-800 text-red-600 min-h-screen">
      <ProjectFilter />
      <div className="mt-2 grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        {projects.map((project) => (
          <Link
            href={`/portfolio/${project.id}`}
            key={project.id}
            className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg border-solid border-2 border-red-600 hover:bg-red-600 hover:text-stone-800 active:bg-gray-200"
          >
            {/* <img
              className="w-full"
              src="/img/card-top.jpg"
              alt="Sunset in the mountains"
            /> */}
            <div className="px-6 py-4">
              <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2">
                {project.project_name}
              </div>
              <p className="text-gray-700 text-base">{project.description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
              <span className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">
                {project.code_link}
              </span>
              <span className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">
                {project.deployment_link}
              </span>
              <span className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">
                {project.primary_language}
              </span>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
        <SideBar styles={styles} />
      </div>
      <p className="mt-4">Phase II:  After completing my personal site, I am taking the time to review all my projects and will be uploading them over the next few weeks. Thanks for your patience.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Portfolio Page",
  description: "Page that displays projects that I have been involved with and includes a filter to filter down projects by languages"
};

// export default PortfolioPage;
```

I don't have any errors in development.  What am i missing?  Thanks in advance.

I have tried varying versions of my export statement and removing export from the const variable.

Comment: You seem to have to share the code for `app/portfolio/list/page.tsx` file as well. and where is `PortfolioPage` file located and what is its file name?

Answer (score 0):

You should default export your page component. If you need to export additional data like `metadata`, consider including it inside the page component

```
import { SideBar } from "@/app/components";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";
import Link from "next/link";
import ProjectFilter from "./ProjectFilter";
import { Primary } from "@prisma/client";
import Head from 'next/head'; // Import Head for handling metadata

// Other imports remain the same...

interface Props {
  searchParams: { language:  Primary };
}

const PortfolioPage = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {
  // Your existing logic...
  
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Portfolio Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Page that displays projects that I have been involved with and includes a filter to filter down projects by languages" />
      </Head>
      <div className="mx-2 pt-8 px-14 bg-stone-800 text-red-600 min-h-screen">
        {/* Your existing JSX */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PortfolioPage;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I tried commenting out the metadata and still the same issue.